# Custom module not loaded

Tags: magento-1.9

We're new to Magento and have made a little module (Module_Catalog) that extends from the Mage_Catalog and we have some custom functionality in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` to create a custom menu, which all works fine.

We currently have an issue with translation files; we created custom translation files called "Module_Catalog.csv" in `/app/locale/[de_DE|en_US]/` which are referenced from the config.xml.

Currently the translation files are working on our Windows dev environments, but not on the Linux staging server. Initially I though that it was an issue with the translation files, however running this test: `Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig('Module_Catalog')->is('active', 'true');` returns false. I've also been logging `Mage::log("loadModuleTranslation: " . $moduleName, null, "Module.log");` in Translate.php in the `foreach` that loads the transations and our module is not showing up there.

When I test `Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig('TM_EasyTabs')->is('active', 'true');` (another module that is installed) and that returns true. I've tested this in several locations.

In `local.xml` we load our model like this:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <navigation>Module_Catalog_Block_Navigation</navigation>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
```

And the `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Module_Catalog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Module_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <class>Module_Catalog_Block</class>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <class>Module_Catalog_Helper</class>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Mage_Catalog>
                    <files>
                        <default>Module_Catalog.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Mage_Catalog>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Mage_Catalog>
                    <files>
                        <default>Module_Catalog.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Mage_Catalog>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

I'm pretty sure that the language files are working properly (because they're fine locally) but on the staging environment they won't load.

What are we forgetting / doing wrong?

Comment: Just a wild thought. Did you put into production the declaration file located in `app/etc/modules` ?

Comment: Marius, I think I love you now. After 2 days of floating around in a life raft. You have saved me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so this question would have an answer.  Based on the comments.

The declaration file of the module is missing.  `app/etc/modules/Module_Catalog.xml`